# How can we change primary domain name of the site in Aegir?

Tags: aegir

I have generated a site using Aegir platform. Now i want to change the primary domain name of the site, is it possible via Aegir configuration.

Comment: Welcome to DA. This sounds more like a support request you should ask Aegir directly. Please have a look at our FAQ [How do I ask a good question?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). As with the minimum information you provided here it's hard to tell what you've tried yourself so far.

Comment: We have an open issue about this with a suggested approach. https://www.drupal.org/project/hostmaster/issues/2951275  Please let me know if that works, then we can document it here and close that issue.